# Subquery to return the latest entry for each parent ID

Tags: sql, db2

I have a parent table with entries for documents and I have a history table which logs an audit entry every time a user accesses one of the documents.

I'm writing a search query to return a list of documents (filtered by various criteria) with the latest user id to access each document returned in the result set.

Thus for

```
    DOCUMENTS
    ID | NAME
    1  | Document 1
    2  | Document 2
    3  | Document 3
    4  | Document 4
    5  | Document 5

    HISTORY
    DOC_ID | USER_ID | TIMESTAMP
    1      | 12345   | TODAY
    1      | 11111   | IN THE PAST
    1      | 11111   | IN THE PAST
    1      | 12345   | IN THE PAST
    2      | 11111   | TODAY
    2      | 12345   | IN THE PAST
    3      | 12345   | IN THE PAST
```

I'd be looking to get a return from my search like

```
    ID | NAME       | LAST_USER_ID
    1  | Document 1 | 12345
    2  | Document 2 | 11111
    3  | Document 3 | 12345
    4  | Document 4 | 
    5  | Document 5 |
```

Can I easily do this with one SQL query and a join between the two tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Revising what Andy White produced, and replacing square brackets (MS SQL Server notation) with DB2 (and ISO standard SQL) "delimited identifiers":

```
SELECT d.id, d.name, h.last_user_id
    FROM Documents d LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT r.doc_id AS id, user_id AS last_user_id
              FROM History r JOIN
                   (SELECT doc_id, MAX("timestamp") AS "timestamp"
                        FROM History
                        GROUP BY doc_id
                   ) AS l
                   ON  r."timestamp" = l."timestamp"
                   AND r.doc_id      = l.doc_id
         ) AS h
         ON d.id = h.id
```

I'm not absolutely sure whether "timestamp" or "TIMESTAMP" is correct - probably the latter.

The advantage of this is that it replaces the inner correlated sub-query in Andy's version with a simpler non-correlated sub-query, which has the potential to be (radically?) more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't get the "HAVING MAX(TIMESTAMP)" to run in SQL Server - I guess having requires a boolean expression like "having max(TIMESTAMP) > 2009-03-05" or something, which doesn't apply in this case.  (I might be doing something wrong...)

Here is something that seems to work - note the join has 2 conditions (not sure if this is good or not):

```
select
    d.ID,
    d.NAME,
    h."USER_ID" as "LAST_USER_ID"
from Documents d
left join History h
    on d.ID = h.DOC_ID
    and h."TIMESTAMP" =
    (
        select max("TIMESTAMP")
        from "HISTORY"
        where "DOC_ID" = d.ID
    )
```

Comment: I guess I could have used max(TIMESTAMP) in the inner query, rather than select top 1 ... order by [TIMESTAMP] desc

Comment: And you should lose the MS SQL Server barbarisms with square brackets - or replace them with DB2 equivalent notation "TIMESTAMP".

Comment: sorry about that... it's all I know

Comment: select
    d.ID,
    d.NAME,
    h."USER_ID" as 'LAST_USER_ID'
from Documents d
left join History h
    on d.ID = h.DOC_ID
    and h."TIMESTAMP" =
    (
        select max("TIMESTAMP")
        from "HISTORY"
        where "DOC_ID" = d.ID
    )

Comment: I'm having to map from Informix to DB2 - parallel but different issues.  :D

Comment: Ok, I tried to fix it for real :)  I don't really know the ISO standard though... although I do know [] are not standard!

Comment: Yes gents the [] are not DB2 standard, the column names as specified (e.g. TIMESTAMP) suffice. One thing I have seen is that DB2 isn't liking the (SELECT...) as a comparison clause in the ON for the JOIN

Comment: Interesting... I wondered if that would work on all databases, it's kind of a strange join clause. Have you tried running Jonathan's query below?

Comment: Yes, thats looking more hopeful. Seems to be returning me the expected results. Generating more test data to verify further. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't use a join, but for some queries like this I like to inline the select for the field.  If you want to catch the situation when no user has accessed you can wrap it with an NVL().

```
select a.ID, a.NAME,
(select x.user_id
 from HISTORY x
 where x.doc_id = a.id
   and x.timestamp = (select max(x1.timestamp)
                      from HISTORY x1
                      where x1.doc_id = x.doc_id)) as LAST_USER_ID
from DOCUMENTS a
where <your criteria here>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be something like this:

```
SELECT ID, Name,  b.USER_ID as LAST_USER_ID
FROM DOCUMENTS a LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT DOC_ID, USER_ID 
          FROM HISTORY
              GROUP BY DOC_ID, USER_ID
              HAVING MAX( TIMESTAMP )) as b
    ON a.ID = b.DOC_ID
```

this might work also:

```
SELECT ID, Name,  b.USER_ID as LAST_USER_ID
FROM DOCUMENTS a 
  LEFT JOIN HISTORY b ON a.ID = b.DOC_ID
GROUP BY DOC_ID, USER_ID
HAVING MAX( TIMESTAMP )
```

Comment: You'd need a LEFT OUTER JOIN to get the last three rows of the required output.

Comment: I couldn't get having max(timestamp) to work on SQL server - does that work on other DBs?

Comment: And you would probably need: GROUP BY DOC_ID, USER_ID, and you'd need to fix up the HAVING clause...

Comment: @Jonathan - do you know if you can use having in this case?  I messed with it a little bit but couldn't get the group by/having to work at all for this.  I'm a SQL noob, I'd love to see how to do it if you know.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select ID, Name, User_ID
From Documents Left Outer Join
History a on ID = DOC_ID
Where ( TimeStamp = ( Select Max(TimeStamp)
                      From History b
                      Where a.DOC_ID = b.DOC_ID ) OR
        TimeStamp Is NULL )  /* this accomodates the Left */
```