# SQLAlchemy Efficient Subquery for Latest Value

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, subquery, select-n-plus-1

The current value of an Entity's `status` attribute can queried as the latest entry in a *EntityHistory* table for that entity, i.e.

```
Entities (id) <- EntityHistory (timestamp, entity_id, value)
```

How do I write an efficient SQLALchemy expression that eagerly loads the current value from the history table for all entities without resulting in N+1 queries?

I tried writing a property for my model, but this generates a query for each (N+1) when I iterate over it. To my knowledge, there is no way to solve this without a subquery, which still seems inefficient to me on the database.

#### Example `EntityHistory` data:

```
timestamp |entity_id| value
==========|=========|======
     15:00|        1|     x
     15:01|        1|     y
     15:02|        2|     x
     15:03|        2|     y
     15:04|        1|     z
```

So the current value for entity 1 would be `z` and for entity 2 it would be `y`. The backing database is Postgres.

Comment: Would a correlated subquery as a [`column_property()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property) work for you? It's loaded during instance load time, not when you access it. You'd have 1 query, which includes a correlated subquery, but that should be ok with proper indexes in place etc, unless you have ridiculous amounts of data or some such.

Answer (score 6):

I think you could use a [`column_property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property) to load the latest value as an attribute of an `Entities` instance along other column-mapped attributes:

```
from sqlalchemy import select
from sqlalchemy.orm import column_property

class Entities(Base):

    ...

    value = column_property(
        select([EntityHistory.value]).
        where(EntityHistory.entity_id == id).  # the id column from before
        order_by(EntityHistory.timestamp.desc()).
        limit(1).
        correlate_except(EntityHistory)
    )
```

A subquery could of course also be used in a query instead of a `column_property`.

```
query = session.query(
    Entities,
    session.query(EntityHistory.value).
        filter(EntityHistory.entity_id == Entities.id).
        order_by(EntityHistory.timestamp.desc()).
        limit(1).
        label('value')
)
```

Performance would naturally depend on proper index being in place:

```
Index('entityhistory_entity_id_timestamp_idx',
      EntityHistory.entity_id,
      EntityHistory.timestamp.desc())
```

In a way this is still your dreaded N+1, as the query uses a subquery per row, but it's hidden in a single round trip to the DB.

If on the other hand having *value* as a property of `Entities` is not necessary, in Postgresql you can join with a [DISTINCT ON ... ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914098/how-to-select-id-with-max-date-group-by-category-in-postgresql/16920077#16920077) query to fetch latest values:

```
values = session.query(EntityHistory.entity_id,
                       EntityHistory.value).\
    distinct(EntityHistory.entity_id).\
    # The same index from before speeds this up.
    # Remember nullslast(), if timestamp can be NULL.
    order_by(EntityHistory.entity_id, EntityHistory.timestamp.desc()).\
    subquery()

query = session.query(Entities, values.c.value).\
    join(values, values.c.entity_id == Entities.id)
```

though in limited testing with dummy data the subquery-as-output-column always beat the join by a notable margin, if every entity had values. On the other hand if there were millions of entities and a lot of missing history values, then a LEFT JOIN was faster. I'd recommend testing on your own data which query suits your data better. For random access of single entity given that the index is in place a correlated subquery is faster. For bulk fetches: test.

Comment: Maybe joining against an aggregate of `MAX(timestamp)` and grouped by entity_id could work? http://stackoverflow.com/a/625171/198927